# How to delete a beta testing app in google play store?

Tags: android

I have an application in google play store as a beta version. I am able to get the beta version link and have provided it for beta testing to the testers.
Now what I need is delete the beta version of the application and upload the application with the same name from different play store account. So what steps do I need to follow to delete the beta version of the application from my current account and upload the application from different account as a production version however the application should have same name as the beta version name?

Comment: You need to ask Google Support about it.

Comment: I guess there is no such option unfortunately contact google play developer support service

Comment: you can un-publish, not sure if this will do what you need

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately you can't delete an app once you have publish it, the only thing you can do is to unpublish it.

As you can see in the warning message displayed before unpublish an app, the app remains available for existing users:

> DO YOU REALLY WANT TO UNPUBLISH THIS APPLICATION?
>
> When you unpublish an application existing users can still use your
>   app and receive app updates. Your app won't be available for new users
>   to find and download on Google Play.

For this reason the package name of your app remains in use. This is a huge problem because the package name must be unique on Play Store, so you can't publish the same app in another account.

The only viable solution is to unpublish the current app, change the package name of your app and upload in the new account.

Comment: are you sure? beta testing apk also we can't delete?

Comment: Is this possible now?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete the app but you can transfer the app to your other account and then upload the production version there.

Here's a link to how to do the transfer request within the Play Store Dev Console.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/checklist/3294213?hl=en&ref_topic=3450986

Answer (score 1):

[image: unpublish app screenshot]

Please try this

Pricing and distribution -> Unpublish

Answer (score -2):

You just have to change the package name inside your app, then you can upload it from the other account.

Comment: So can I upload on the different account with same name but different package name.

Comment: Yes. I think you can even change the app name afterwards, just the package is your UID and therefore final.